# How to programmatically get prediction accuracy in AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am building flight delay prediction via AWS SageMaker. I want to programmatically get the prediction accuracy for each pair of airports. So for all flights from  London to New York, the accuracy of the total predictions can be different than for Tokio -> London. So when any flight from London to New York is being predicted, I want to show also the probability that the prediction is correct for that concrete flight (London -> New York). The prediction accuracy of the entire model can be different than the concrete Flight. So I need prediction accuracy for each Origin -> Destination pair.
Is there something in SageMaker to get such information, or do I need to manually write a script and calculate it through historical predictions?

I was reading SageMaker documentation and there was only model monitoring tools which are giving information about entire model and to for some conditions like per Origin -> Destination.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear without the sharing details on the type of model used, data etc. but I'll try to answer with my the best possible knowledge. SageMaker endpoints offers Model Monitoring, among which one of the metrics of "Model Quality" is Accuracy. So, in order to get the accuracy of your model, you will need to capture GroundTruth and the predicted label to compare. SageMaker FAQs and documentation explains it well [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor.html).

Note: I work for AWS, but the opinions are my own.